# Тире или запятая в БСП?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, сложное-предложение, бсп

Противопоставление (тире), простое перечисление фактов (запятая) или присоединение (тире)? После каждого предложения моё мнение.

————————

1. **Вам необязательно возглавлять проект ( — / , ) вы можете войти в его консультационный совет.**

Запятая, поскольку это скорее перечисление, по смыслу сложно поставить союз "а" или "но". Тире можно поставить, если второе предложение имеет оттенок присоединения.

2. **Если вы обычный специалист в отделе, вам допустимо знать лишь свой узкий круг обязанностей; но если вы руководитель или владелец бизнеса, это непозволительная роскошь ( — / , ) вам нужно быть специалистом во всём.**

Тире: присоединение дополняющей мысли.

3. **Чересчур яркие цвета и излишние навороты ни к чему ( — / , ) нужен просто стильный дизайн и отчётливая структура.**

Запятая: перечисление, оттенок противопоставления очень слабый.

4. **Людям не нужны эмоциональные паразиты ( — / , ) им нужны друзья, которые будут заряжать их энергией.**

Не уверен. Можно трактовать как противопоставление: "Людям нужны не *эмоциональные паразиты*, а *друзья, которые будут заряжать их энергией*". Можно трактовать как перечисление синонимичных понятий — отсутствия необходимости в эмоциональных паразитах и потребности в друзьях, которые будут заряжать энергией.

5. **Так что не разговаривайте с коллегами и с начальником робко и официально ( — / , ) общайтесь с ними как с друзьями, только без фамильярностей.**

Тире: явное противопоставление ("*Не разговаривайте робко и официально*, а *общайтесь как с друзьями*").

6. **Не будьте пассивным сотрудником ( — / , ) во время обсуждений активно высказывайте свою позицию.**

Запятая: не быть пассивным сотрудником (отрицается пассивность) и активно высказывать свою позицию (утверждается активность) — синонимичные понятия. Таким образом, имеет место перечисление фактов. Можно поставить и тире, если есть оттенок присоединения или пояснения (пояснение того, как не быть пассивным сотрудником). Кстати, в случае пояснения подойдёт и двоеточие.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мое менение:

1. Вам необязательно возглавлять проект ( — / , ) вы можете войти в его консультационный совет.

Можно представить как перечисление (запятая), можно увидеть здесь пояснение (говоря "необязательно возглавлять проект", мы подразумеваем "войти в его консультационный совет") — тогда тире. Это разные оттенки смысла.

2. Если вы обычный специалист в отделе, вам допустимо знать лишь свой узкий круг обязанностей; но если вы руководитель или владелец бизнеса, это непозволительная роскошь ( — / , ) вам нужно быть специалистом во всём

Как-то коряво. Смысл предложения (а именно, что являетя непозволительной роскошью) понять можно, но трудно. Читать такое предложение неприятно. Я бы не хотел рассуждать о пунктуации в таком варианте. Я бы расширил предложение, добавил *то*, убрал точку с запятой, например так:

*Если вы обычный специалист в отделе, то вам допустимо знать лишь свой узкий круг обязанностей, но если вы руководитель или владелец бизнеса, то такое положение вещей (такое узкое знание, такая узость интересов)  — (это) непозволительная роскошь для вас, вам нужно быть специалистом во всём.*

Здесь пояснение. Наличие тире перед *это* заставляет поставить запятую.

3. Чересчур яркие цвета и излишние навороты ни к чему ( — / , ) нужен просто стильный дизайн и отчётливая структура.

Можно представить как перечисление (запятая), можно увидеть здесь противопоставление — тогда тире. Мое предпочтение — менее эмоциональный вариант (запятая).

4. Людям не нужны эмоциональные паразиты ( — / , ) им нужны друзья, которые будут заряжать их энергией.

Запятая или тире отразят выбранную автором степень эмоциональности.

5. Так что не разговаривайте с коллегами и с начальником робко и официально ( — / , ) общайтесь с ними как с друзьями, только без фамильярностей.

Согласен, здесь прежде всего противопоставление.

6. Не будьте пассивным сотрудником ( — / , ) во время обсуждений активно высказывайте свою позицию.

Запятая (перечисление) или тире  (пояснение). Это разные оттенки смысла. Двоеточие излишне, пауза с "нажимом" — слишком нравоучительно.

Comment: Я дополнил 2-е предложение контекстом, иначе действительно непонятно, что "это". Дополните, пожалуйста, свой ответ.

Comment: @ВасилийЕфименко  Дополнил.